# Change value outside function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method to check book title in my DB already exist or not. This is my method:

```
public function checkTitle(Request $request){
        $newTitle = $request->input('title');
        $newTitle = $this->cleanTitle($newTitle);
        $id = $request->input('id_user');
        $titleStatus = false;

        $id_user = DB::table('user')->where('id', $id)->first()->id;
        $book = DB::table('book')->where('id_user', $id_user)->get();

        $book = collect($book)->each(function ($values) use ($newTitle, $titleStatus){
                $value = $values;
                $value->checkTitle = $this->cleanTitle($value->value);
                if($value->checkTitle == $newTitle){
                    $titleStatus = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        dd($titleStatus);
}
```

**Question**

I want to check all title using each() to know the title is new or not. If title book is new I set $titleStatus false and if already exist I set true. But after iterate variable $titleStatus is not change to true the value is still false. Why the value is not change? any solution to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to pass `$titleStatus` by reference? Otherwise `use` will only create a copy of it for your function to work with, but any changes you make to the value inside the function, won't reflect on the outside.

Comment: If you want to check if the title is already in the DB, this is a lot of code... you can basically do that in one line. also the line `$value = $values;`makes no sense...  `->each(function ($value)`. you also collect $book, that is already a collection.

Comment: sorry for my bad code, but all i want is to change  $titleStatus to true after that i exit the iteration

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: the DB table 'book' has a column 'value' that contains the title?

Comment: How I changes the value and reflect on the outside? @Cbroe

Comment: passing by reference you do by adding a `&` when passing the var. i don't really know if it works in a `use`, let me know...  `use ($newTitle, &$titleStatus)`

Comment: yes, the table have column title and I name it value.

Comment: can you share the topic talk about reference by adding a &?